# Add Sub-IDs to already defined ID numbers

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a list of IDs in column A.  Some are repeated.  In column B I would like a formula that produces Sub-IDs based on column A that are unique.

I.e. If COl A = 1,  Col B = 1.1.   then if i add another row with ID =1, column B realises this is the second row with ID 1 and puts the sub id as 1.2?

```
ID  Sub-ID
1   1.1
2   2.1
3   3.1
4   4.1
4   4.2
2   2.2
3   3.2
4   4.3
```

Hopefully this makes sense? I think i need column B to add 0.1 to col A, then lookup if any of the cell above it are the same, and if they are, Add 0.1 to that?

Answer (score 0):

```
=A2+COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)/(10^LEN(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)))
```

Assuming your data is layed out in column A like below, place the above formula in B2 and copy down.

working on a minor problem of trailing zeros not displaying.  The only way I can currently think about in terms of dealing with this in a formula would be to treat the output as text instead of a number.

[image: POC]

The TEXT work around to getting your trailing zero is:

```
=A2&RIGHT(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)/(10^LEN(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2))),LEN(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)/(10^LEN(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2))))-1)&IF(MOD(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2),10),"",REPT(0,LEN(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2))-1))
```

[image: TEXT POC]

which can apparently be simplified to:

```
=A2+COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)/(10^LEN(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)))&IF(MOD(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2),10),"",REPT(0,LEN(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2))-1))
```

Comment: If treating like text, can use formula: `=A2&"."&COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)`

Comment: @tigeravatar EVEN NICER!  Great job of demonstrating fewer of excels built in functions hehehe